# Google OAuth2 how to get user email without user.profile?

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

How do I get access to the user email without requiring access to the whole of the user's profile?

The `tok` I get after calling `oauthConfig.Exchange` below doesn't seem to provide a programmatic way to access the "ID token", even if I include "email" in the scopes.

```
import (
  ...
  "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
  "golang.org/x/oauth2"
  "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
  "google.golang.org/api/gmail/v1",
  "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

var (
  ctx = context.Background()

  oauthConfig = &oauth2.Config{
    ClientID: ...,
    ClientSecret: ...,
    RedirectURL: ...,

    // ... but it looks like what I want is userinfo.email
    Scopes: [ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile" ],

    Endpoint: google.Endpoint,
  }
)

// Handler for the redirect URL.
func redirectHandler(c *gin.Context) {
  tok, _ := oauthConfig.Exchange(ctx, c.Query("code"))
  httpClient := oauthConfig.Client(ctx, tok)
  gmailService, _ := gmail.NewService(ctx, option.WithHTTPClient(httpClient)
  userProfile, _ := gmailService.Users.GetProfile("me").Do()

  // And now we have the user's email address
  // userProfile.EmailAddress
}

// Omitting main etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

You apear to be trying to use the gmail api,

```
gmailService.Users.GetProfile("me").Do()
```

You are not requesting a gmail api scope.  To access that method you need to use one of the following scopes.

- https://mail.google.com/
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata

If all you want to know is their email address try adding just scope email and see what happens

```
{
  "access_token": "Redacted", 
  "id_token": "redacted", 
  "expires_in": 3599, 
  "token_type": "Bearer", 
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email openid", 
  "refresh_token": "redacted"
}
```

But if we decode the id token we get my email.

```
{
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
  "azp": "407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "aud": "407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "sub": "117200475532672775",
  "email": "XXXX@gmail.com",
  "email_verified": true,
  "at_hash": "hMyUqSfZ0ZFhvNfGF0RndA",
  "iat": 1690878599,
  "exp": 1690882199
}
```

Note you can use either of these.

- email
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email